# How do I avoid page breaks inside tables and groups in BIRT?

Tags: java, eclipse, report, birt

When creating reports using BIRT 2.3.1, I don't want page breaks inside tables or groups; if the table doesn't fit in the space available at the page, I want to put the entire element in the next page.

Using previous versions of BIRT it was possible to set pageBreakInside to "avoid", but it didn't work. In BIRT 2.3.1 this (useless) option was removed, since it wasn't implemented correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the 'hard' problems in reporting.  Tried to get it in 2.3 and we missed, rather than have people thinking that they were doing something wrong (when it didn't work), we backed it out in 2.3.1.

This is high on the priority list for 2.5 (June 2009).  Sorry to disappoint, we just ran out of time.